# AS3 - Sum of Number var and precision issue

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, numbers, precision

I've two variable of type Number but the sum of them is not correct.

This is my scenario:

```
var a:Number = 1.1;
var b:Number = 2.2;
var c:Number = a + b;
```

result of c is 3.3000000003 instead 3.3

How can I resolve this issue?

Obviously the precision of 'a' and 'b' in the sample is 1 number after comma, but can be several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expected behaviour. It is actually pretty hard to express certain numbers in the binary number system. A close aprox. wil result in:

```
1.00011001100110011001100110011001... (1.09999..)
```

sadly 1.2 is equally hard:

```
1.00110011001100110011001100110011... (1.19999..)
```

as you might note the 1100 keeps repeating. Just like it isn't possible to express 1/3 in the decimal system.

The solution could be to use less precision by rounding the c.

```
trace(c.ToString(1));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I must change my approach because I can't lose precision.